# npm run build elifecycle

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am a new to react and I want to create production build out of my code. But when I run `npm rub build` it gives me this error in `.log` file

> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
>
> 1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/Cellar/node/9.11.1/bin/node',
>
> 1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
>
> 1 verbose cli   'run',
>
> 1 verbose cli   'build' ]
>
> 2 info using npm@5.6.0
>
> 3 info using node@v9.11.1
>
> 4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
>
> 5 info lifecycle jenna-web-frontend@0.1.0~prebuild:
> jenna-webfrontend@0.1.0
>
> 6 info lifecycle jenna-web-frontend@0.1.0~build:
> jenna-web-frontend@0.1.0
>
> 7 verbose lifecycle jenna-web-frontend@0.1.0~build: unsafe-perm in
> lifecycle true
>
> 8 verbose lifecycle jenna-web-frontend@0.1.0~build: PATH:
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/markopetricic/Documents/Projects/staging-jenna-web-front/node_modules/.bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
>
> 9 verbose lifecycle jenna-web-frontend@0.1.0~build: CWD:
> /Users/markopetricic/Documents/Projects/staging-jenna-web-front
>
> 10 silly lifecycle jenna-web-frontend@0.1.0~build: Args: [ '-c',
> 'react-scripts build' ]
>
> 11 silly lifecycle jenna-web-frontend@0.1.0~build: Returned: code: 1
> signal: null
>
> 12 info lifecycle jenna-web-frontend@0.1.0~build: Failed to exec build
> script
>
> 13 verbose stack Error: jenna-web-frontend@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
>
> 13 verbose stack Exit status 1
>
> 13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.
> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:285:16)
>
> 13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:180:13)
>
> 13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.
> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
>
> 13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:180:13)
>
> 13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:936:16)
>
> 13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
> (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
>
> 14 verbose pkgid jenna-web-frontend@0.1.0
>
> 15 verbose cwd
> /Users/markopetricic/Documents/Projects/staging-jenna-web-front
>
> 16 verbose Darwin 17.3.0
>
> 17 verbose argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/9.11.1/bin/node"
> "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
>
> 18 verbose node v9.11.1
>
> 19 verbose npm  v5.6.0
>
> 20 error code ELIFECYCLE
>
> 21 error errno 1
>
> 22 error jenna-web-frontend@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
>
> 22 error Exit status 1
>
> 23 error Failed at the jenna-web-frontend@0.1.0 build script.
>
> 23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
> additional logging output above.
>
> 24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "jenna-web-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "cookieconsent": "^3.0.6",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "react": "^16.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.0",
    "react-fade-in": "^0.1.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-s3": "^1.2.4",
    "react-s3-uploader": "^4.8.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1",
    "react-stay-scrolled": "^2.1.1",
    "sfcookies": "^1.0.2",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set PORT=3001 && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Do you have any idea why this happened?

Comment: can you post your package.json?

Comment: Just updated, can you check it again @tobias-kutter

Comment: tried to update react-scripts to current version (1.1.4)?

Comment: @Mare did you find any solutions, I have come across the same problem also and dont know how to solve